# For every pair $n,d$ such that $d \ge (n-1)/2$ prove that $G$ on $n$ vertices with minimum degree $d$ is edge d-connected.

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

For every pair $n,d$ such that $d \ge (n-1)/2$ prove that $G$ on $n$ vertices with minimum degree $d$ is edge d-connected.

None of my observations I was able to obtain seem to be useful. I am just able to prove that $G$ is connected. I will keep on investigating and will update as soon as I find something interesting or somehow helpful.

Any help is appreaciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is saying all vertices have at least d edges so prove the graph is d-connected.

So if you have proven it is connected then just use simple contradiction.

Assume  c < d edges is the minimum number of edges needed to disconnect the graph - call the disconnected vertex A.  Since vertex A had d or more edges, so it is still connected to at least one more vertex - call it B. Pretty simple from there.

Comment: Could you please add a little extra info? I can't really see how this implies that $G$ is edge $d$-connected. As long as I understand, you are considering minimum set of cut edges to be edges connecting vertex $A$ with the rest of $G$ (the size of this set is apparently $(n-1)/2$). Couldn't there be a different set of cut edges, let's call it $X$ while $|X| \lt (n-1)/2 $?

Comment: sorry that was my bad. I know how to do it, but it has been awhile since i wrote a formal graph theory proof.

assume c is the smallest edge cut to disconnect G_1 from G_2.  take the smaller set of vertices.  

each vertex in this set used to be connected to more then half the graph.  so even if this set of vertexes is half of the vertex each vertex is connected to the other graph by atleast an edge.  how many such edges.  well if

d=(n+1)/2+b  b>0 and c<d then each vertex has atleast b edges going to the other graph.   or atleast (n/2)b edges

good?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Could you please update your original answer, so I can actually mark it as answer? May be you could give it a bit more formal look and use latex. It's a really simple and clever way of formatting important mathematical notations. Here I am adding great [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) . It is really good pracitice if you are plannign to answer more questions :-). Thanks!